# How to store "<" in an XML attribute for configuration section?>

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, escaping

I'm using a custom configuration section in my web.config file for ASP.NET

One of my fields is:
      `<add percent="5" label="<5%" />`

As you can see in label I have a "<" sign - this is causing errors. How can I store this value there without having compile issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The escape sequence for this character in XML is

```
&lt;
```

The lt stands for "less than"

Comment: +1 yup you have to use the escape characters in the configuration file.